# Error in if else in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I get an error in the query below. Why ?

```
DECLARE @Vr varchar(50);
SET @Vr = N'Infos';
IF @Vr = FAR
UPDATE MyTable
SET TAR = @Vr
```

Error - Invalid column name 'FAR'.

I am using the right database and right table. Then, why does this happen ?

My logic is if Column Far = variable Vr, then update Column TAR.

Comment: Change the `IF @Vr = FAR UPDATE MyTable SET TAR = @Vr` to `UPDATE MyTable SET TAR = @Vr WHERE FAR = @Vr`.

Comment: If FAR is in MyTable Brad is right, if it is in another table AmirrezaKeshavarz is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you are checking the column name and not that particular column's value. I suggest you try dynamic sql. This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure) can be useful.
As far as I've understood, if your  `@Vr = 'FAR'` then update field `TAR` else do something else. In that case, see my below query

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @valueToBeUpdatedInYourColumn nvarchar(100)
set @valueToBeUpdatedInYourColumn = 'this value will be your updated value'
SET @Vr = 'Infos';
IF @Vr = 'FAR'
   BEGIN
     SET @SQL = '

                 UPDATE MyTable
                 SET TAR= '''+@valueToBeUpdatedInYourColumn+'''
                '
      EXEC(@SQL)
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
         ...
   END
```

The number of single quotes `'` is very important

Answer (score 2):

This is the true code:

```
DECLARE @Vr varchar(50);
SET @Vr = N'Infos';
IF @Vr = (select far from <table_name>)
Begin
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET TAR = @Vr

END
```

Comment: No, FAR is supposed to be a column and not a hard-coded string !

Comment: I don't want to type a solution... get rid of the if and make it a where criteria on the update.

Comment: @Love2Learn - actually, there is a reason why i used if else. there are more conditions involved. I did not want to add those and clutter the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
    DECLARE @Vr varchar(50);
    SET @Vr = N'Infos';
   -- IF @Vr = FAR
    IF ( select Count(*) from mytable where ColumnFar =@Vr) >0
    BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable
    SET TAR = @Vr where ColumnFar =@Var
    END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 -- Goes your condition
 END
```

Or use CASE

```
  DECLARE @Vr varchar(50);
   SET @Vr = N'Infos';

UPDATE MyTable
       SET TAR =
                 CASE
                   WHEN ( @Vr = FAR)
                                   THEN 'FAR'
                   Else
                    NULL -- Or any other value you want.
                 END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `BEGIN`/`END` for your `IF` statement

```
DECLARE @Vr varchar(50);
SET @Vr = N'Infos';

UPDATE MyTable
SET TAR = @Vr
WHERE FAR = @vr
```

EDIT:

Use a where clause instead of an IF block.

Comment: same problem persists.

Comment: this is not gonna work because he wants to update all the rows by a condition , not some of the rows .

Comment: How do you figure? I don't see how updating the entire table accomplishes something